# * ReferenceError: session is not defined *

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, socket.io

### Estou com um problema, em compartilhar os dados do usuário do Express cookie e funções de sessão! o objetivo é armazenar tais dados no meu Socket.IO, mas apresenta um problema de erro de referência onde diz que a sessão não está definida. Eu tenho pouco conhecimento sobre isso, gostaria de saber como e onde vou nomear essa sessão?

---

Trecho do código onde o erro aponta :  const currentSession = session[sessionID]

```
//Verificado de regra
io.use((socket,next) =>{
    const cookieData = socket.request.headers.cookie;
    const cookieObj = cookie.parse(cookieData);//Gera um objeto com dados do cookie
    const  sessionHash = cookieObj[config.sessionKey] ||'';// Acessa o hash da sessão 
    const sessionID = sessionHash.split('.')[0].slice(2);
    store.all((err,sessions)=>{
        const currentSession = session[sessionID]; // referenciar a sessão ID
        if( err|| !currentSession){
            return next(new Error('Acesso Negado!'));
        }
        socket.handshake.session = currentSession;
        return next();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenta colocar sessions inves de session, sessions esta sendo passada como parametro

```
store.all((err,sessions)=>{
      const currentSession = sessions[sessionID]; // referenciar a sessão ID
```

Comment: Meu DEUS ! QUE VERGONHA, ERA ISSO MESMO kkkkkkk Desculpa, valeu obg!